# Is there any way to test every possible combination of a sentence with cypress?

Tags: cypress, array-merge

Let say there are three array.

```
const initialArray = ['He', 'She', 'It']

const middleArray = ['is', 'was', 'were']

const lastArray = ['a dog', 'a cat', 'a wizard']
```

What I mean is if any of these 3 combinations comes the sentence is valid but the sentence need to be

`'initialArray middleArray lastArray'` only this sequence combination is correct others are false

I am trying to write something like this which is hardcoded but it won't work when the number of variables increase.

```
cy.get(`.${className} .legend_title`).should((key) => {
            let mytext = key.text();
            expect(mytext.trim()).to.be.oneOf([
              'He is a dog',
              "He is a cat",
              'He is a wizard',
              'She is a dog', .......
            ]);
          });
```

Answer (score 3):

An easier way is to use regex to match against the sentence. You can programmatically create the matcher if you choose.

Here is a working [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/integration/everyCombinationOfSentence.md).

```js
// regex for simpilicity
const matcher = /(He|She|It)\s(is|was|were)\s(a)\s(dog|cat|wizard)/i;
cy.get("#sentence").invoke("text").should("match", matcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you do a nested forEach Loop for all three arrays, you can check all the combinations like this:

```js
initialArray.forEach((init) => {
  middleArray.forEach((mid) => {
    lastArray.forEach((last) => {
      console.log(init + ' ' + mid + ' ' + last)
    })
  })
})
```

Combinations:

[image: Combinations]

Adding all this, your code should look like this:

```js
let sentenceArray = [] //initialize an empty array

initialArray.forEach((init) => {
  middleArray.forEach((mid) => {
    lastArray.forEach((last) => {
      sentenceArray.push(init + ' ' + mid + ' ' + last) //populate array with all combinations
    })
  })
})

cy.get(`.${className} .legend_title`)
  .invoke('text')
  .then((myText) => {
    expect(mytext.trim()).to.be.oneOf(sentenceArray)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @jjhelguero answer but here's another way using `.flatMap()` to create the permutations.

```js
const initialArray = ['He', 'She', 'It']
const middleArray = ['is', 'was', 'were']
const lastArray = ['a dog', 'a cat', 'a wizard']

const permutations = initialArray.flatMap(i => 
  middleArray.flatMap(m => 
    lastArray.flatMap(l => `${i} ${m} ${l}`)
  )
)
console.log(permutations)
console.assert(permutations.includes('She was a cat'))
```

```js
expect(mytext.trim()).to.be.oneOf(permutations);
```

Answer (score 0):

To build a regex from the array of values, use the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#literal_notation_and_constructor)

```js
const initialArray = ['He', 'She', 'It']
const middleArray = ['is', 'was', 'were']
const lastArray = ['a dog', 'a cat', 'a wizard']

const initialChoices = initialArray.join('|')
const middleChoices = middleArray.join('|')
const lastChoices = lastArray.join('|')

let re = new RegExp(`(${initialChoices})\s(${middleChoices})\s(${lastChoices})`, 'i')
 
cy.get("#sentence").invoke("text").should("match", re);
```

Note with regex you get more flexibility for handling edge cases, for example this can't be handled by `.trim()`

```js
"She          was     a cat"
```

In the regex change `\s` (one space) to `[\s]+` (one or more spaces).